# Linearity of Expectation - Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

If I have the equation: 
 $E[X+E[Y]]=E[X]+E[E[Y]]$ 
 Using the formula: $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ 
But from other hand I can say that: $E[X+E[Y]]=E[X]+E[Y]$ 
 Using the formula: $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$ because $E[Y]$ is a number like $b$
So what is the true one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. $E[Y]$ is not random so $E[E[Y]]$ is same as $E[Y]$.

Comment: I can say that $E[E[E[Y]]] = Y$ ?
If yes, how?

Comment: It is not $Y$, it is $EY$. Expectation of any constant is the constant itself and $EY$ is a  constant. @Pedro

Comment: Thank you very much!!